# libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: kali-linux

I use kali linux os , I have a problem with `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` library

```
/Bureau/PacketTracer62Student/bin$ ./PacketTracer6 
./PacketTracer6: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 20):

You need to install [`libssl1.0.0`](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/openssl):

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0
```

For future reference, you can install `apt-file` to find this out yourself:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
apt-file search libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

Comment: I get this


Package libssl1.0.0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.

Comment: having the same problem on Centos, but could not find package for ssl1.0.0, Anyone knows answer for Centos?

Comment: how install in centos 7? :O

Comment: Interestingly, the only Kali package that provides that library nowadays (2021) is the `powershell` package.

Answer (score 5):

1. sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
2. add deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main
3. sudo apt update && apt-cache policy libssl1.0-dev
4. sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev

source: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/101245/how-do-i-install-the-libssl1-0-0-package/112232#112232?newreg=b4deba3288294d1e82b88241d5d0c295

Comment: It worked just fine. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Using `reinstall` worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev --reinstall
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what finally worked for me in Kali 2021.1:

Downloaded 'libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.6_amd64.deb' from:
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.6_amd64.deb

installed it on Kali linux with:

```
dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.6_amd64.deb
```

I used amd64 package relevant to my arch. if you want a different architecture check here http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/

confirm it's installed with:

```
dpkg --list | grep -i libssl
```

you should see libssl1.0.0 in the installed list

Comment: yes ! I've forgotten than `dpkg -i` could workaround version issue of `apt-get install` when we want fix upgrade issue of an old application.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the source list with `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` to add the following line

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main
```

Then `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install libssl1.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

DEBIAN DIETPI

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.11_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.11_amd64.deb

If you trying install LAN Messenger, this could help too:

sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get install libqt5multimediawidgets5
sudo apt-get install libqt5x11extras5

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The OP uses Kali, your suggestion is using Ubuntu files. That's a big no-no, using non-Kali resources breaks Kali. It can only be maintained via its own repositories.

Answer (score -1):

Just download the binary package file from [here](https://rosa.pkgs.org/2014.1/rosa-main-updates-x86_64/lib64crypto1.0.0-1.0.2q-1-rosa2014.1.x86_64.rpm.html) and copy the libcrypto.so.1.0.0 file to /usr/lib .
That solves the problem!

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: Must be from the site's side. Try getting the file from here https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/libcrypto++6_5.6.4-8_amd64.deb.html  and copy the binary package file to /usr/lib